# Removing todo items

Tags: javascript

I am have trouble figuring out how to get this code to work. I am trying to remove a todo item based on which one was clicked. My goal eventually is to delete based on which button was clicked.

Here is my code so far:

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4'
let text;
let todos = [];

document.querySelector('#new-todo').addEventListener('keypress', e =>
{
    text = e.target.value;

    if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTodo(text);
        renderTodo();
        console.log(todos);
    }
});

const addTodo = text =>
{
    todos.push(
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        text
    });
}

const renderTodo = () =>
{
    let node = document.createElement("p");
    let textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("todos").appendChild(node);
}

document.querySelector('#todos').addEventListener('click', () =>
{
    removeTodo(todo.id);
    console.log(todos);
});

const removeTodo = id => 
{
    const todoIndex = todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === id)

    if (todoIndex > -1) 
    {
        todos.splice(todoIndex, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: It would probably be easier if `todos` was an object indexed by `id` rather than an array that you would have to `.find` through in order to identify a particular object

Comment: can you elaborate on this please?